# send data between activity in sqllite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have problem in my code 
I want to send data when the user clicks 
and receive data in another activity 
example

I want to send position of items and on I go to second activity

I want to display form table where position = description field

**my code**

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Details.class);
                i.putExtra("id",position);
                startActivity(i);
          }
        });

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
            TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
            ImageButton im=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im);
            Intent data=getIntent();
            String des=data.getStringExtra("id");
           // myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            Cursor curser= DBAdapter.myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sweet where id = '" + des + "'", null);
            curser.moveToPosition(0);
            while (!curser.isAfterLast()) {
                t1.append(curser.getColumnIndex(0));
                curser.close();
            }
```

**Second Activity**

```
        Intent data=getIntent();
        int des=data.getIntExtra("id", 1);
        //String s= String.valueOf(des);
        //
        // Cursor sq= myDbHelper.myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from sweet where description = '"+des+"')",null);
        try {
            //String query = "SELECT * FROM sweet WHERE " + des + " = name";
            String query = "SELECT * FROM sweet WHERE " + des + " = name";
            SQLiteDatabase database = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
           //Cursor sq = myDbHelper.myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from sweet", null);
           Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
            String description = cursor.getString(2);
            t1.setText(description);
        }
```

[tabele](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ0ML.jpg)

My table

id 
name
description 
this is 3 field

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Quick fix: just remove the quotes! long fix: read about sql injections in sqlite android, activityLifeCycle, passing data between activities (just google that)

Comment: i google that but no answer i found 
the problem is on i get the intent i dont know who to use the postion of item to use it to display what field i want

Comment: post your another activity code

Comment: i post the another activity

Comment: @MuhammadHsant can you add toast to see whether it display the id ?

Comment: `i.putExtra("id",position);` if you wan to pass an `id` as your extra then use `id` when calling `putExtra`, not `position`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent data=getIntent();
 int des=data.getIntExtra("id", 1);

  try {
        SQLite database=myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(SELECT * FROM sweet WHERE desccription =? ",  new String[]{String.valueOf(des)}, null);

  Details details=new Details();

   if(cursor !=null)
  {
     while(cursor.moveToNext())
  {
     String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(myDbHelper.Description));
     details.setDescription(description);
      t1.setText(description);
  }
}
```

**Details**

```
public class Info {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;


    public void setID(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return this.id;
    }  

public String setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }  


public String setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description=description;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }
```

Comment: thanks you for this but my data base external i use sqlBrwoser and add my sql in assest folder
And why you do the class details and why you use .new String[]{String.valueOf(des)